# How to set max Permgen settings in production Google App Engine server

Tags: google-app-engine, out-of-memory

I am running a web module on google app engine using automatic scaling with the default F1 server instance.  Yesterday, I noticed a PermGen, Out of Memorry server exception occurred in production.  This concerns me, because my users receive a blank screen when this error happens as the response to their web request, and it will cause a lot of confusion.  Also, my app is in a pilot phase and there are just a couple of users and no load, so to receive a permgen, OutOfMemory server exception means more could be on the way as things ramp up.

Is there a way to increase the max PermGen memory allocation on a google app engine configuration?  I've searched and not found anything about changing the setting on a production app engine server (only development server, which I've done successfully).  If I change the server I'm using to something with more memory (e.g. F2 server instance), will that help?  I'm assuming that even a higher memory server instance will still use the default max permGen setting, so I don't think so.

Thanks for letting me know how to reduce the possiblity of receiving these OutOfMemory errors in production google app engine servers.

Here's the stack trace of the error

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space at
>   sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63) at
>   sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateMethod(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:77)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:46)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1936)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1462)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:417) at
>   java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1182) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1936)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1462)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2140)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2064)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1936)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1462)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:417) at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.SessionManagerUtil.deserialize(SessionManagerUtil.java:56)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.MemcacheSessionStore.getSession(MemcacheSessionStore.java:38)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.loadSession(SessionManager.java:330)

Comment: I don't think you can change the PermGen memory without managed VMs. Changing PermGen would mean that the whole scaling mechanism in app engine would have to adjust because fewer instances can be run on a single VM. Therefor the obvious choice would be to now allow it. It looks like you're having big chunks of data in your session or at least that's where the exception originates from. However memcaches are limited to 1 MB so i assume the memory consumption that causes this happens somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I'm going to try reducing my user session footprint as a first attempt.  App engine documentation has a little blurb talking about how session data is persisted to a data store and it also uses mem cache for speed.  [google docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Enabling_sessions).  If that doesn't help, I may need to go with a managed VM as you suggested, if that allows me to tweak the permgen settings.

Comment: @KurtHartmann If I were in your situation, I would jump straight to MVM, Since with it you'll definitely be able to tweak what you want easily. Reducing user session isn't necessarily easy, and if you end up not reducing enough, you'll hit the same limitation. I have to point out that MVMs are still in beta though and therefore you should be careful about running anything critical of it.

Comment: @Patrice The managed VM hosting sounds like a good long-term solution for me.  Any idea when it moves out of beta testing?  My app is still 3 months away from being ready for general availability.  Will managed VMs be stable and production ready by then?

Comment: @KurtHartmann I'd love to give you info on this, but I don't have any precise date unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get more control into the instance that is hosting your application is to use [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/).

While minimizing user session could help in this instance, it's not always easy and not guaranteed (since you can minimize but still hit the limit).

Be careful about using managed VMs (remember they scale differently too, so make sure to read about [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/config), especially the scaling section), since they are still in Beta, which means they shouldn't be used in production for critical applications.